# c# How to use the new Version Helper API

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, dllimport

Since [OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx) is now not reliable since Windows 10 has been released (this function reports Windows 8 for Windows 10), I'm attempting to use the new Version Helper API functions in my C# application. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx) they are.

I apologize if this is simply a issue with my DLL import, but here is my attempt to pull in these new methods to detect the OS correctly.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool IsWindows7OrGreater();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool IsWindows8OrGreater();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool IsWindows8Point1OrGreater();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool IsWindows10OrGreater();
```

Whenever I'm calling these methods, I'm getting:

Exception is: EntryPointNotFoundException - Unable to find an entry point named 'IsWindows7OrGreater' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'.

Am I doing something wrong? Anyone have any ideas? Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** Please see the accepted answer and take a look at [this code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/707502/Version-Helper-API-for-NET) for a good start on porting these methods over to C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a little more complicated than that. The "functions" are actually macros defined in `VersionHelpers.h`.

If you think of it, that's the only way to do it - they can't add functions to older Windows versions retroactively.

You have to port the macros over to C#.

Comment: Ah, I see. That does make sense. Thanks very much for the quick response. Here's a code project that I found that provides a good start to porting these over: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/707502/Version-Helper-API-for-NET

Comment: @Krumelur An example would've severely helped this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your code must have a Manifest that contains

```
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
        <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.--> 
        <!-- Windows 10 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
        <!-- Windows Vista -->
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
        <!-- Windows 7 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        <!-- Windows 8 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>
```

This tells the OS your code supports the newer OS

Use the following class

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VersionHelper
{
    public static class VersionHelper
    {
        const byte VER_EQUAL = 1;
        const byte VER_GREATER = 2;
        const byte VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
        const byte VER_LESS = 4;
        const byte VER_LESS_EQUAL = 5;
        const byte VER_AND = 6;
        const byte VER_OR = 7;

        const byte VER_CONDITION_MASK = 7;
        const byte VER_NUM_BITS_PER_CONDITION_MASK = 3;

        //
        // RtlVerifyVersionInfo() type mask bits
        //

        const uint VER_MINORVERSION = 0x0000001;
        const uint VER_MAJORVERSION = 0x0000002;
        const uint VER_BUILDNUMBER = 0x0000004;
        const uint VER_PLATFORMID = 0x0000008;
        const uint VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR = 0x0000010;
        const uint VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR = 0x0000020;
        const uint VER_SUITENAME = 0x0000040;
        const uint VER_PRODUCT_TYPE = 0x0000080;

        // wProductType    
        // Any additional information about the system.This member can be one of the following values.
        const byte VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER = 0x0000002;
        const byte VER_NT_SERVER = 0x0000003;
        const byte VER_NT_WORKSTATION = 0x0000001;

        //
        // _WIN32_WINNT version constants
        //
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_NT4 = 0x0400;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K = 0x0500;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP = 0x0501;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WS03 = 0x0502;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN6 = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WS08 = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_LONGHORN = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 = 0x0601;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8 = 0x0602;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE = 0x0603;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD = 0x0A00; /* ABRACADABRA_THRESHOLD*/
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10 = 0x0A00; /* ABRACADABRA_THRESHOLD*/

        const bool FALSE = false;

        static byte LOBYTE(ushort w)
        {
            return ((byte)(w & 0xff));
        }

        static byte HIBYTE(ushort w)
        {
            return ((byte)(w >> 8 & 0xff));
        }


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern ulong VerSetConditionMask(ulong ConditionMask, uint TypeMask,   byte  Condition );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool VerifyVersionInfoW(ref OSVERSIONINFOEXW lpVersionInformation, uint dwTypeMask, ulong dwlConditionMask);


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct OSVERSIONINFOEXW
        {
            public int dwOSVersionInfoSize;
            public int dwMajorVersion;
            public int dwMinorVersion;
            public int dwBuildNumber;
            public int dwPlatformId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            public string szCSDVersion;
            public UInt16 wServicePackMajor;
            public UInt16 wServicePackMinor;
            public UInt16 wSuiteMask;
            public byte wProductType;
            public byte wReserved;
        }


        public static bool
        IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(ushort wMajorVersion, ushort wMinorVersion, ushort wServicePackMajor)
        {
            var osvi = new OSVERSIONINFOEXW
            {
                dwOSVersionInfoSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOEXW))
            };

            var dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(
                VerSetConditionMask(
                VerSetConditionMask(
                    0, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
                       VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
                       VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);

            osvi.dwMajorVersion = wMajorVersion;
            osvi.dwMinorVersion = wMinorVersion;
            osvi.wServicePackMajor = wServicePackMajor;

            return VerifyVersionInfoW(ref osvi, VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, dwlConditionMask) != FALSE;
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsXPOrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsXPSP1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 1);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsXPSP2OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 2);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsXPSP3OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 3);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsVistaOrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsVistaSP1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 1);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 2);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows7OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows7SP1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), 1);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows8OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows8Point1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsThresholdOrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows10OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsServer()
        {
            var osvi = new OSVERSIONINFOEXW
            {
                dwOSVersionInfoSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOEXW)),
                wProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION
            };

            var dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(0, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, VER_EQUAL);

            return !VerifyVersionInfoW( ref osvi, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, dwlConditionMask);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481241.aspx, **VerifyVersionInfo** is deprecated in Windows 10. Is there any non-deprecated API left in Windows 10 that can give the OS version?

Comment: @FrancisLitterio He's using `VerifyVersionInfoW`, not `VerifyVersionInfo`, but even so, that's what the helper functions are for that he also included, and also, just because something is deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work - it generally means Microsoft has replaced it (i.e. these helper functions Paul included).  Either should still work, but you want to use his `IsWindows10OrGreater()` function, above.

Comment: Was able to run the functions on Windows 7 without a manifest, so I would think if it can run these on 7, wouldn't it work on 10 without any problems without it, too?  Shouldn't it already have the same `VerifyVersionInfoW()` function, and just need to send in the number of 10 as `ushort wMajorVersion` to `IsWindowsVersionOrGreater()` to see if it gets 10 when passed to it?

Answer (score 5):

VersionHelpers functions are not exported in any dll, but rather defined in VersionHelpers.h file,
in order to utilize the functionality in your C# code you can copy the functionality from the header file,

Import those 2 functions:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern ulong VerSetConditionMask(ulong dwlConditionMask, uint dwTypeBitMask, byte dwConditionMask);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool VerifyVersionInfo([In] ref OsVersionInfoEx lpVersionInfo, uint dwTypeMask, ulong dwlConditionMask);
```

Define the following structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct OsVersionInfoEx
{
    public uint OSVersionInfoSize;
    public uint MajorVersion;
    public uint MinorVersion;
    public uint BuildNumber;
    public uint PlatformId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string CSDVersion;
    public ushort ServicePackMajor;
    public ushort ServicePackMinor;
    public ushort SuiteMask;
    public byte ProductType;
    public byte Reserved;
}
```

Then use the following function:

```
static bool IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(uint majorVersion, uint minorVersion, ushort servicePackMajor)
{
    OsVersionInfoEx osvi = new OsVersionInfoEx();
    osvi.OSVersionInfoSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(osvi);
    osvi.MajorVersion = majorVersion;
    osvi.MinorVersion = minorVersion;
    osvi.ServicePackMajor = servicePackMajor;
    // These constants initialized with corresponding definitions in
    // winnt.h (part of Windows SDK)
    const uint VER_MINORVERSION = 0x0000001;
    const uint VER_MAJORVERSION = 0x0000002;
    const uint VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR = 0x0000020;
    const byte VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
    ulong versionOrGreaterMask = VerSetConditionMask(
       VerSetConditionMask(
           VerSetConditionMask(
               0, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
           VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
       VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
    uint versionOrGreaterTypeMask = VER_MAJORVERSION |VER_MINORVERSION | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR;
    return VerifyVersionInfo(ref osvi, versionOrGreaterTypeMask, versionOrGreaterMask);
```

}

Comment: Kudos, runs without a hitch or manifest file (at least on Windows 7)!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to work with interop/unmanaged code or add a target manifest.

[Get Windows OS version with WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48119148/5248400)

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned here and on [GetVersionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexw) and [Environment.OSVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion#remarks) docs, [GetVersionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexw) behavior/availability changed with Windows 8.1. (And for .NET < 5.0, [Environment.OSVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion) reflects this)
The same applies to the [VerifyVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-verifyversioninfow) function. If you use .NET 5 or Core, you can just use [Environment.OSVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion#remarks) again and by the way, my colleague working on our Core project, excluded the code that was querying WMI using [ManagementObjectSearcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher) with directives as it did not compile for Core )

An alternate way would be to use the PInvoke from other answers with the Windows SDK counterparts (from ntdll.dll) of these functions

- [RtlGetVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlgetversion) ( can use either the [OSVERSIONINFOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_osversioninfow) a [OSVERSIONINFOEXW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_osversioninfoexw) structure, which are aliases for non-SDK counterparts. Just be sure to set the dwOSVersionInfoSize before calling it so it knows which one you are referencing. )
- [RtlVerifyVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlverifyversioninfo)

They use the same structs as the functions from kernel23.dll, and can be used the same way (also using the [VerSetConditionMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-versetconditionmask) function as substitute for the documented [VER_SET_CONDITION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-ver_set_condition) macro but only Unicode versions are available, so be sure to annotate the structs with [StructLayoutAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute) with [Charset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset) set to [CharSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset).Unicode as C# defaults to ANSI)

So code already posted should give reliable results if the following imports are used instead:

(In case you can't or don't want to use WMI or the registry)

```
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern ulong VerSetConditionMask(ulong dwlConditionMask, uint dwTypeBitMask, byte dwConditionMask);

            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            private static extern uint RtlGetVersion(ref OSVERSIONINFOW lpVersionInformation);

            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            private static extern uint RtlGetVersion(ref OSVERSIONINFOEXW lpVersionInformation);

            [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
            private static extern bool RtlVerifyVersionInfo([In] ref OSVERSIONINFOEXW lpVersionInformation, uint dwTypeMask, ulong dwlConditionMask);
```