# How can I detect which version of Windows is running?

Tags: c#, windows

I have an application which runs as a Word add-in. (VSTO).

It runs on many PCs all over the world.  In certain cases I need to trouble shoot problems (obviously remotely) and have a reporting mechanism which tells me which Windows OS is running - I use `Environment.OSVersion` in .NET.  At least it did until Windows 10.

There is an article on MSDN ([Targeting your application for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) about creating an application manifest which will enable the correct version to be returned.

But my application is a DLL, not an EXE and so won't really accommodate the XML code referred to in that article.

Is there no way to just ask Windows, "What version are you?  Really, I won't cry if you admit to the real version".

Or an entry in the registry or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280055/check-windows-version-from-registry-c-sharp

Comment: As an aside - why do you care what version you're running on? (Especially, as there will be different versions of Windows 10)

Comment: I just want to be able to narrow down the situations in which errors occur.  And knowing what OS does help with this.  Maybe a particular error only happens on Windows 10 - it would be nice to know that.

Comment: Purely in case people find this looking for information on versions of Windows 10 via their local, friendly search engine: for Universal apps, there is a [good blog post on feature detection](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/)

Comment: Thank you Kevin Kal - that gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If WMI is not an option for you, You could use the SDK counterparts of the [GetVersionEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexw) functions, [RtlGetVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlgetversion). They don't lie.

If you use .NET 5.0 or Core, Environment.OSVersion reports the actual version of Windows.

I posted more detail about this as addition to the answers on this other thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64804643/2240196

EDIT: Added example code as requested. (You probably don't need all of it)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VersionHelper
{
    public static class VersionHelper
    {
        // The C(++) macro VER_SET_CONDITION mentioned in the documentation for RtlVerifyVersionInfo seems to be equivalent to the VerSetConditionMask function in kernel32.dll

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-versetconditionmask
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern ulong VerSetConditionMask(ulong dwlConditionMask, uint dwTypeBitMask, byte dwConditionMask);

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlgetversion
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        private static extern int RtlGetVersion(ref OSVERSIONINFOW lpVersionInformation);

        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        private static extern int RtlGetVersion(ref OSVERSIONINFOEXW lpVersionInformation);

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlverifyversioninfo
        [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
        private static extern bool RtlVerifyVersionInfo([In] ref OSVERSIONINFOEXW lpVersionInformation, uint dwTypeMask, ulong dwlConditionMask);

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-osversioninfoexw
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private struct OSVERSIONINFOEXW
        {
            internal uint dwOSVersionInfoSize;
            internal uint dwMajorVersion;
            internal uint dwMinorVersion;
            internal uint dwBuildNumber;
            internal uint dwPlatformId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            internal string szCSDVersion;
            internal ushort wServicePackMajor;
            internal ushort wServicePackMinor;
            internal ushort wSuiteMask;
            internal byte wProductType;
            internal byte wReserved;
        }
        
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-osversioninfow
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private struct OSVERSIONINFOW
        {
            internal uint dwOSVersionInfoSize;
            internal uint dwMajorVersion;
            internal uint dwMinorVersion;
            internal uint dwBuildNumber;
            internal uint dwPlatformId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
            internal string szCSDVersion;
        }

        /*
         * RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEX(A/W) and OSVERSIONINFOEX(A/W) are aliases for the same structures
         * RTL_OSVERSIONINFO(A/W) and OSVERSIONINFO(A/W) are aliases for the same structures
         * */

        // These constants initialized with corresponding definitions in
        // winnt.h (part of Windows SDK)
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-ver_set_condition
        private const byte VER_EQUAL = 1;
        private const byte VER_GREATER = 2;
        private const byte VER_GREATER_EQUAL = 3;
        private const byte VER_LESS = 4;
        private const byte VER_LESS_EQUAL = 5;
        private const byte VER_AND = 6;
        private const byte VER_OR = 7;

        private const byte VER_CONDITION_MASK = 7;
        private const byte VER_NUM_BITS_PER_CONDITION_MASK = 3;

        private const uint STATUS_SUCCESS = 0x00000000;

        //
        // RtlVerifyVersionInfo() type mask bits
        //
        private const uint VER_MINORVERSION = 0x0000001;
        private const uint VER_MAJORVERSION = 0x0000002;
        private const uint VER_BUILDNUMBER = 0x0000004;
        private const uint VER_PLATFORMID = 0x0000008;
        private const uint VER_SERVICEPACKMINOR = 0x0000010;
        private const uint VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR = 0x0000020;
        private const uint VER_SUITENAME = 0x0000040;
        private const uint VER_PRODUCT_TYPE = 0x0000080;

        // wProductType    
        // Any additional information about the system.This member can be one of the following values.
        private const byte VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER = 0x0000002;
        private const byte VER_NT_SERVER = 0x0000003;
        private const byte VER_NT_WORKSTATION = 0x0000001;


        // You can customize this to check for the condition(s) you need using any field from the OSVERSIONINFOW struct with the corresponding VER_ and VER_<operator> constants
        public static bool IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(uint majorVersion, uint minorVersion, ushort servicePackMajor = 0, uint buildNumber = 0)
        {
            var osVerInfo = new OSVERSIONINFOEXW
            {
                dwOSVersionInfoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOEXW)),
                dwMajorVersion = majorVersion,
                dwMinorVersion = minorVersion,
                wServicePackMajor = servicePackMajor,
                dwBuildNumber = buildNumber
            };
            ulong versionOrGreaterMask = VerSetConditionMask(
                VerSetConditionMask(
                    VerSetConditionMask(
                        0, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
                    VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
                VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
            uint versionOrGreaterTypeMask = VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR;
            if (buildNumber > 0)
            {
                versionOrGreaterMask = VerSetConditionMask(versionOrGreaterMask, VER_BUILDNUMBER, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);
                versionOrGreaterTypeMask |= VER_BUILDNUMBER;
            }
            return RtlVerifyVersionInfo(ref osVerInfo, versionOrGreaterTypeMask, versionOrGreaterMask);
        }

        public static bool IsWindowsServer()
        {
            var osVerInfo = new OSVERSIONINFOEXW
            {
                dwOSVersionInfoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOEXW)),
                wProductType = VER_NT_WORKSTATION
            };
            ulong dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(0, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, VER_EQUAL);
            return !RtlVerifyVersionInfo(ref osVerInfo, VER_PRODUCT_TYPE, dwlConditionMask);
        }
        
        public static int GetWindowsBuildNumber()
        {
            var osVerInfo = new OSVERSIONINFOW
            {
                dwOSVersionInfoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOW))
            };
            if (STATUS_SUCCESS == RtlGetVersion(ref osVerInfo)) // documented to always return STATUS_SUCCESS
                return (int)osVerInfo.dwBuildNumber;
            throw new Win32Exception("Failed to determine Windows build number.");
        }

        // Other functions replicating SDK Version Helper functions
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/version-helper-apis

        //
        // _WIN32_WINNT version constants
        //
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_NT4 = 0x0400;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN2K = 0x0500;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP = 0x0501;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WS03 = 0x0502;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN6 = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WS08 = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_LONGHORN = 0x0600;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 = 0x0601;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8 = 0x0602;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE = 0x0603;
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WINTHRESHOLD = 0x0A00; 
        const ushort _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10 = 0x0A00;

        const bool FALSE = false;

        static byte LOBYTE(ushort w)
        {
            return ((byte)(w & 0xff));
        }

        static byte HIBYTE(ushort w)
        {
            return ((byte)(w >> 8 & 0xff));
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsXPSP1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 1);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsXPSP2OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 2);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsXPSP3OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP), 3);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsVistaOrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsVistaSP1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 1);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 2);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows7OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows7SP1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7), 1);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows8OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN8), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows8Point1OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE), 0);
        }

        public static bool
        IsWindows10OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_WIN10), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari Thanks for your feedback. I added some code. I hope this provides enough context information.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String GetOSVersion()
{
    var wmiEnum = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT Version FROM  Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().GetEnumerator();
    wmiEnum.MoveNext();
    return wmiEnum.Current.Properties["Version"].Value as String;
}
```

Returns 6.1.7601 on my W7 system and 10.0.14393 on my Server 2016 system.

No need to add a target manifest.

Answer (score -1):

WMI is the best way to do this kind of stuff You can use this to retrieve OS informations :

```
ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = 
       new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM  Win32_OperatingSystem");

OS.Name = ((string)objMOS["Caption"]).Trim();
OS.Version = (string)objMOS["Version"];
OS.MaxProcessCount = (uint)objMOS["MaxNumberOfProcesses"];
OS.MaxProcessRAM = (ulong)objMOS["MaxProcessMemorySize"];
OS.Architecture = (string)objMOS["OSArchitecture"];
OS.SerialNumber = (string)objMOS["SerialNumber"];
OS.Build = ((string)objMOS["BuildNumber"]).ToUint();
```

This can fetch the OS details for you.

Comment: @Mohti, your code does not work, thats all I know. My coding skills do not mather

Comment: @Mohit Black is right. Your code is crap. Thanks for wasting my time and the time of everyone else who stumbled upon this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `GetVersionEx` Win32 API.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that Windows 10 in fact is version 6.4. Ver 6.0 is Vista, 6.1 - 7, 6.2 - 8.

Comment: This only works if you've got the appropriate manifest entries.  Otherwise, it'll just flat-out lie and tell you that everything is Windows 8.